# CommandButton action executes twice when a bean method takes a long time to respond

Tags: jsf, primefaces, glassfish

I'm working on a project using Java 8, PrimeFaces 6.0 and deploy on GlassFish 4.1.

I have a commandButton to call `testMethod` and has been working without any problems when the task that executes the method takes a couple of seconds or minutes. But, when the task takes 30 minutes or more the `testMethod` is executed twice (It can be seen in the server log), which is very strange.

So, mi questions are:

- Why the action is executed twice with tasks that take a long time? and,
- How can I avoid it?

```
<h:form id="myForm">
  <p:panel id="options" header="OPTIONS">
    <div align="center">
      <p:commandButton id="btnVolcar" action="#{testController.testMethod()}" value="Send" update=":growl"/>
    </div>
  </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

TestController:

Perform database operations (call a stored procedure)

```
public String testMethod() {
    try {
        // store procedure
        testService.callToSP();
        Logger.getLogger(TestController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage("Success", "finished");
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TestController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(ex, ex.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception ex1) {
        Logger.getLogger(TestController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
    } finally {
        return URI;
    }
}
```

One important thing is that it is difficult to test since when the project is run in debug mode there is no double execution.

Comment: Can you post a fully reproducible example (server configuration, controller method code)? What do you mean with it's executed twice? Browser console trace two requests? Do you get any error(timeout/etc) on the server console log?

Comment: I can't imagine why but if you think your button is being clicked twice you could add `onstart="PF('yourbutton').disable();" oncomplete="PF('yourButton').enable();` to disable the button until the AJAX returns.

Comment: @WoAiNii I edit the post, thanks by you help

Comment: @Melloware I already did that, even remove the button using javascript code

Comment: I need more details about why you considered your action executed twice. What's in your server log? If you try with a page with only that form, the result is the same? What if you convert that action into an actionListener? Are you sure the problem isn't within the stored procedure?